# vhdl delay line implementation attribute

Tags: xilinx

A newbie question related to vhdl attributes. In this implementation of 128-deep 8-bit delay line on LUT RAM, attribute part confuses me.

```
entity srl_128_lutram is 
  generic ( 
    LENGTH     : integer := 128; 
    ADDRWIDTH : integer := 7; 
    WIDTH      : integer := 8); 
  port ( 
    CLK        : in  std_logic; 
    SHIFT_IN  : in  std_logic_vector(WIDTH-1 downto 0); 
    SHIFT_OUT : out std_logic_vector(WIDTH-1 downto 0)); 
end srl_128_lutram; 

architecture behavioral of srl_128_lutram is 

  signal CNTR : std_logic_vector(ADDRWIDTH-1 downto 0); 
  type ram_type is array (0 to LENGTH-2) of std_logic_vector(WIDTH-1 downto 0); 
  signal RAM : ram_type := (others => (others => ’0’)); 

  attribute ram_style : string; 
  attribute ram_style of RAM : signal is "distributed"; 

begin 

  counter : process (CLK) 
  begin 
    if CLK’event and CLK = ’1’ then 
       if CNTR = conv_std_logic_vector(LENGTH-2, ADDRWIDTH)  then 
         CNTR <= (others => ’0’); 
       else 
         CNTR <= CNTR + ’1’; 
       end if; 
    end if; 
  end process counter; 

  memory : process (CLK) 
  begin 
    if CLK’event and CLK = ’1’ then 
       RAM(conv_integer(CNTR)) <= SHIFT_IN; 
       SHIFT_OUT                 <= RAM(conv_integer(CNTR)); 
    end if; 
  end process memory; 

end behavioral;
```

My question is what purpose of attributes are here ? What would happen without these two lines ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EDIT :
**Attributes** are used to give some directives to synthetizer.
The attribute syntax is a bit confusing but the meaning of your line is the following : For my signal *RAM* use the attribute **ram_style** with the value **distributed**. The attribute will never be used later in the code, it has already given his informations.

Note : attributes are differents from a synthetizer to another.

OLD :
The attribute **RAM_STYLE** gives to the synthetizer the type of physical cells use to implement your RAM.

In your case it will choose LUT rams. So it will consume some LUT rams of your total LUT ram ressources in your FPGA. You can also to use block RAM.

If you don't use this attribute, synthetizer will choose by itself between these 2 cells (probably with ressource and performance considerations).

*Sources* : https://www.xilinx.com/support/documentation/sw_manuals/xilinx2012_3/ug901-vivado-synthesis.pdf (page 36)

Comment: My understanding of attribute (in this case) was that someone, somewhere, whould call RAM'ram_style if it needs (ram_style)  attribute value but I don't see so. That's my confussion comes from.

Comment: Maybe I don't understand well your comment but I think you don't understand the key word **attribute** more than **ram_style**. Am I right ?

Comment: Yes it is about attribute from the beginning. Back to reading.

Comment: For example https://www.slideshare.net/77saur/attributes-in-vhdl - page 16 and call to attribute PLACEMENT, was something that I expected to see in code.

Comment: Sorry I didn't read closely your original post, I made an edit to my answer. Is this clearer for you ?

Comment: That's OK. Reminds to .net attributes - something which is "emitted".

Comment: To be honnest, I'm not familiar with user-defined attribute (PLACEMENT in your example). It seems to be constant and different than synthesis attribute (RAM_STYLE) which will be understood by the synthetizer.